# Live output in jQuery HTML5 range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, range

I'm trying to get a live output from a HTML5 input range slider into a javascript variable.  Right now, I'm using `<input type="range" id="rangevalue" onchange="arduino()">`

The way I have it working is doing what I want, but it's not "live."
I want to have it so while you're dragging the slider, it updates the variable, and not only once you let go.  For example: when I'm dragging the slider from 1 to 5, I want the variable to update while I'm dragging, so it will update with 1,2,3,4,5 and not only jump from 1 to 5 once I release the slider.

Is it possible to do such a thing?  Any recommendations?  I was using the jQuery slider plugin, but it was not touch compatible, which eliminated its purpose.

Thanks for all help in advance!

EDIT - I must not have explained well enough, I know how to get the value of a range slider, I just want to get a "live" output from it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("#rangevalue").mousemove(function () {
    $("#text").text($("#rangevalue").val())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2md8h9x6/)**

Or in plain JS:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
inp.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I +1'd your method which was the way I was originally planning on going ;)

Comment: This runs anytime the mouse moves over the slider - not just when you clicking and moving the slider.

Comment: @VagueExplanation anytime the mouse moves over the slider? What do you mean, and in what browser?

Comment: I tried it in Safari. You can do a test with logging in the console any time the code inside the function runs. It makes sense for what it says though - it's a mousemove event that occurs when moving the mouse cursor over the an element with the id "rangevalue". It runs without clicking. You only need to move your cursor over the element.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. What we need to do is use `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()` with a Boolean value to keep track that we are holding down the mouse `mousedown`. When the mouse is held down set `mousedown` to true and use a `setTimeout` that keeps updating the value. This way while you are dragging slider the value is being constantly updated. For example:

**HTML**

```
<label id="text">0</label>
<input type="range" value=0 min=0 max=10 id="rangevalue">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var mouseDown = false

$("#rangevalue").mousedown(function() {
   mouseDown = true;
    updateSlider()
});

$("#rangevalue").mouseup(function() {
    mouseDown = false;
});

function updateSlider() {
    if(mouseDown) {
        // Update the value while the mouse is held down.
        $("#text").text($("#rangevalue").val());
        setTimeout(updateSlider, 50); 
    }
}
```

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02d1uLz2/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the oninput attribute.

```
    <input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1" 
   oninput="arduino()" onchange="arduino()">
```

[More Information on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853670)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this solution a good fit for this problem

```js
$("#rangevalue").on("input", function(){ 
  updateSlider() 
});

function updateSlider() {
    // Update the value while the mouse is held down.
    $("#text").text($("#rangevalue").val());
    setTimeout(updateSlider, 50); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="text">0</label>
<input type="range" value=0 min=0 max=10 id="rangevalue">
```

Answer (score 0):

To update while dragging the slider, listen for the `mousemove` event.

For this solution, the target range input element (slider), uses a `mousemove` event handler that will update for the current (live) position value of the slider.

To limit movement detection to when the slider is being dragged:

- On `mousedown`, attach a handler for `mousemove` events.
- On `mouseup`, remove the `mousemove` handler.

This is in addition to a `change` event handler, which is the advised way of getting any final changes to an elements value.

Try it on [fiddle ⎤↗︎](https://jsfiddle.net/yarns/4mheavcn/13/)

```html
<input type="range" id="rangevalue">
```

```js
var rangevalue = document.getElementById('rangevalue');

rangevalue.addEventListener("change",    arduino);
rangevalue.addEventListener("mousedown", enabletracking);
rangevalue.addEventListener("mouseup",   disabletracking);

function enabletracking()  { rangevalue.addEventListener(   "mousemove", arduino); }
function disabletracking() { rangevalue.removeEventListener("mousemove", arduino); }
```

**Touch Support**

Further more you may want to add touch support as some browsers handle things differently.

One thing is touch events can trigger other events we are listening to which will cause problems if we're updating from everywhere.
Disabling this default behaviour is possible but has other side effects. For example, page scrolling is usually handled by touch events and will not work while default behaviour is disabled.

```js
rangevalue.addEventListener("touchstart",  enableTouchTracking );
rangevalue.addEventListener("touchend",    disableTouchTracking);
rangevalue.addEventListener("touchcancel", disableTouchTracking);

function enableTouchTracking(event)
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    rangevalue.addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
 }
function disableTouchTracking(event) 
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    rangevalue.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
 }
function handleTouchMove(event)
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    arduino();
 }
```

Comment: the jquery tag was present however i ignored it because the way it was included in the question seems to me to imply that they use jquery, not that the solution is required to use it. plain javascript is sufficient IMaHO.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is working with your Code.

```
<input type="range" id="rangevalue" onchange="arduino()">
<p id="t"></p>
    <script>
        function arduino() {
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = document.getElementById("rangevalue").value;
}</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9cqy9ce/4/)

Comment: The OP wants to show the value changing as the slider is being dragged.

Comment: The value is changing ( tested in Safari on MacBook Pro)

Comment: Not while you move the slider it's not, only after you stop.

Comment: Which browser + OS are you using?