# use multiple live slider on html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

i am new the Javascript and want to solve the following problem. The html code below shows two live slider inputs in one form. but only one is working. ( source:  [Live output in jQuery HTML5 range slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429492/live-output-in-jquery-html5-range-slider))

So how can i use multiple sliders with different values on the same web page?

```js
$("#rangevalue").mousemove(function () {
                $("#text").text($("#rangevalue").val())
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Timing:</title></head>
<body>
<h1>TIMING:</h1>

<form action="/cgi-bin/can/test.cgi" method="post">

<table style="width:300px" border="1">
<th>time</th>
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="range" name="p" value=16.08 min=0.01 max=32.08 id="rangevalue" step ="0.01"><label id="text" >16.08</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="range" name="p" value=100 min=50 max=150 id="rangevalue" step ="0.01"><label id="text">100</label> sec.
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><input style="font-size:25px" type="submit" value="START">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have duplicated the `id` attributes in your HTML when they must be unique. You need to convert the code to use classes instead.

To do that you can select the `rangevalue` elements, and then use `.next()` to find the related `.text` element, like this:

```js
$(".rangevalue").on('change mousemove', function() {
  $(this).next(".text").text(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:300px" border="1">
  <th>time</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="range" name="p" value="16.08" min="0.01" max="32.08" class="rangevalue" step="0.01">
      <label class="text">16.08</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="range" name="p" value="100" min="50" max="150" class="rangevalue" step="0.01">
      <label class="text">100</label>sec.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Great. I am very thankful for you fast and competent help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".rval").mousemove(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.tlabel').text($(this).val())
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Timing:</title></head>
<body>
<h1>TIMING:</h1>

<form action="/cgi-bin/can/test.cgi" method="post">

<table style="width:300px" border="1">
<th>time</th>
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="range" class="rval" name="p" value=16.08 min=0.01 max=32.08 id="rangevalue" step ="0.01"><label class="tlabel" id="text" >16.08</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="range" class="rval" name="p" value=100 min=50 max=150 id="rangevalue" step ="0.01"><label class="tlabel" id="text">100</label> sec.
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><input style="font-size:25px" type="submit" value="START">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```